# URL rewriting doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, dynamic, redirect

There are some pages in this format:

http://www.saglikkosesi.net/soru-ve-yanitlari-goster?page=2

I want them to appear in this format:

http://www.saglikkosesi.net/soru-ve-yanitlari-goster/page/2

I used the following code in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule soru-ve-yanitlari-goster/page/(.*)/ soru-ve-yanitlari-goster?page=$1
RewriteRule soru-ve-yanitlari-goster/page/(.*) soru-ve-yanitlari-goster?page=$1
```

Nothing changed. What can I do to fix this? (I use WordPress platform for my web site. But I can't use permalink feature for this redirection as this pages are external pages and I can't control them via WP admin.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `.htaccess` files are enabled by your Apache configuration?

By the way, you do that by setting `AllowOverride All` in the `<Directory` section of your `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: I am not sure where httpd.conf file is but I can edit .htaccess file. I edited it before to redirect some pages.

Comment: Hey, where have you placed the `.htaccess` file? Is it in the root folder of your domain? Or is it inside the `soru-ve-yanitlari-goster` folder?

Comment: Hello. It is in the root folder.

Comment: Okay then, it's reasonable that it should not work. Place it inside the folder and correct the references accordingly.

Comment: Thank you but there is no folder called "soru-ve-yanitlari-goster" since it is a page and I am using WordPress.

Comment: Ah, sorry, thought the wordpress installation was in that folder.

Comment: Sorry, ran a few tests, could not figure out what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You need `RewriteCond` to access the query string and capture the relevant part:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^/soru-ve-yanitlari-goster$ soru-ve-yanitlari-goster/page/%1?
```

Comment: I typed the code above into .htaccess file but nothing changed. What am I missing?